# Making component library with Vue and vue routers

Tags: vue.js, package, vuejs3, vue-component

My requirement is to create a standalone vue application for a feature and install it in 3 different main vue applications. So let's say my feature is user management. It has table, creation, edit and delete. I need to implement this in one vue application and install it in another vue applications. In order to do that, I have created a vue application and the parent component is called `UserManagement.vue`. In order to keep the same background I am using this as a parent component and I have created child components for table list,create. Below is my routers

```
{
        path: '',
        component: UserManagement,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                name: 'UserList',
                component: UserList,
            },
{
                path: '/add',
                name: 'UserAdd',
                component: UserAdd,
            },
        ],
    },
```

I need to display the table list by default. When I run this alone, it perfectly goes to the list component. But when I installed this to external vue application, it only goes to `UserManagement.vue` component and it doesn't go to `UserAdd.vue` component. Below is my `main.ts` in the consuming app.

main.ts

```
// main application/src/main.ts
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import mainRouter from './router'
import store from './store'
import UserManagement from '@stekz/user-management/src/UserManagement.vue'

const app = createApp(App)

// Use the store and mainRouter directly
app.use(store)
app.use(mainRouter)
app.component('UserManagement', UserManagement)

app.mount('#app')
```

Below is the `main.ts` in my component library app

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

import i18n from './i18n/index'
import './styles.scss'

const app = createApp(App)

app.use(i18n)
app.mount('#user-management-app')

export { app }
```

what am I doing wrong here? I tried everything.